# Quarkus SmallRye Graphql-Client Mutation Query

Tags: graphql, quarkus, smallrye

I try to execute a Graphql Client Query. Sadly I am not able to find any kind of documentation or examples on how to do a simple Mutation using the Dynamic Graph QL Client. Here is the documentation https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-graphql-client.

```
mutation mut {
  add(p: {
    amount: {0},
    fromCurrencyId: {1},
    reference: {2},
    terminalKey: {3},
    toCurrencyId: {4}
  }) {
    address
    toCurrencyAmount
    rate
    createdAt
    expireAt
  }
}
```

{0}..{4} are variable place holder.
Does someone know how to execute this query with the DynamicGraphlQlClient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having declared your server side mutation following the *Eclipse MicroProfile* API as follows:

```java
@GraphQLApi
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyGraphQLApi {

    @Mutation
    public OutputType add(@Name("p") InputType p)) {
        // perform your mutation and return result
    }

}
```

You can then use the `DynamicGraphQLClient` declaratively to perform the mutation using the `DynamicGraphQLClient#executeSync` method with a `io.smallrye.graphql.client.core.Document` constructed after your mutation structure:

```java
@Inject
private DynamicGraphQLClient client;

public void add() {
    Document document = Document.document(
        operation(
            OperationType.MUTATION,
            "mut",
            field(
                "add",
                arg(
                    "p",
                    inputObject(
                        prop("amount", "amountValue"),
                        prop("fromCurrencyId", "fromCurrencyIdValue"),
                        prop("reference", "referenceValue"),
                        prop("terminalKey", "terminalKeyValue"),
                        prop("toCurrencyId", "toCurrencyIdValue")
                    )
                )),
            field("address"),
            field("toCurrencyAmount"),
            field("rate"),
            field("createdAt"),
            field("expireAt")
        )
    );

    JsonObject data = client.executeSync(document).getData();
    System.out.println(data.getString("address"));
}
```